# Why does the nth-child() CSS selector consider elements that are set to display:none?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've noticed some odd behavior with the nth-child() selector. It seems to consider elements set to `display: none` as well. Is there any way to bypass this behavior?

The problem I'm having is that certain tags are being added/removed dynamically. They're all set to `display: none` but i can't change my nth-child() selector every time.

Here's a minified representation of the problem:

```
    <head>
        <style>
            .container div{
                height: 20px;
            }
            .top, .content{
                display:none
            }
            .mid:nth-child(2){
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="mid"></div>
            <div class="mid"></div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here, `.mid:nth-child(2)` doesn't work because it is technically the 4th child. So, for this to work I would need `.mid:nth-child(4)` Is this actually normal or can I bypass this? If it is normal, why does it behave this way?

Comment: *Is there any way to bypass this behavior?* --> no

Comment: `display:none` does not remove the element from the DOM, so they still count

Comment: Any reason this question was downvoted? I guess this wouldn't be a problem normally but I'm using Shopify and so it tends to insert certain <style> and <script> tags between elements. This could potentially mess up an nth-child() selector.

Comment: @jaimish11 in that case, an `:nth-of-type()` selector would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

**No, this is expected behaviour**

CSS selectors work against a DOM tree, not a visual representation. This becomes more obvious if you think that the `display: none` rule requires (if applied via a stylesheet) a selector to target that element. If the element could no longer be seen by a CSS selector after being hidden, then the rule that was styling it as hidden would no longer be applied and the element would reappear.

Comment: Oh wow yes. Never thought of it like that. Thanks for the clarification.